# how to write scrapy which start_url is the output of the previous spider?

Tags: python, scrapy, sitemap

I wrote sitemap scrapy like below:

```
class filmnetmapSpider(SitemapSpider):
      name = "filmnetmapSpider"
      sitemap_urls = ['http://filmnet.ir/sitemap.xml']
      sitemap_rules = [
            ('/series/', 'parse_item')
      ]
      def parse_item(self, response):
         videoid = response.xpath('/loc/text()').extract()
```

and extract all url from in it;

I want write another scrapy spider ,Which start_url is the output of the previous spider(sitemapSpider)

how can i do it ??

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of database or file to store results of one spider and read them in another.

```
class FirstSpider(Spider):
    """First spider crawls something end stores urls in file, 1 url per newline"""
    name = 'first'
    start_urls = ['someurl']
    storage_file = 'urls.txt'

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        with open(self.storage_file, 'a') as f:
            f.write('\n'.join(urls) + '\n')

class SecondSpider(Spider):
    """Second spider opens this file and crawls every line in it"""
    name = 'second'

    def start_requests(self):
        file_lines = open(FirstSpider.storage_file)
        for line in file_lines:
            if not line.strip():  # skip empty lines 
                continue
            yield Request(line.strip())
```

Comment: When I print url  ,there is nothing inside it,so does not store anything in .txt file

Answer (score 1):

Let say you get output from your first spider in csv format and the code below will read that file line by line and scrape it using your xpath.

```
class Stage2Spider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'stage2'
allowed_domains = []
start_urls = []
read_urls = open('collecturls.csv', 'r')
for url in read_urls.readlines():
    url = url.strip() 
    allowed_domains = allowed_domains + [url[4:]]
    start_urls = start_urls + [url]
read_urls.close()
```

hope it helps.